# Light between 3 way switches and installation of electronic timer switch

Tags: multiway-switch

an amateur here looking for some advise on installing an Ascend STW700W smart timer in to an existing 3 way switch.

I've done this a few times before, but this is the first time that I have come across what I think is the set up called "light between 3 way switch".  From what I can see I have a 2 wire line input that doesn't immediately power the switch in the box, but rather powers a switch in another room (the other part of the 3-way), which is confusing me no end.  Ascend provides a wiring setup, but i their 3 way wiring they don't have two travelers (see other picture).  Any advice would be gratefully received[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the innards of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Yeah, seeing some random dude's drawing of *his* wiring doesn't tell us a thing about yours.  There are at least 5 ways to configure a 3-way circuit.